Geo nodes: Translate a single instance
I'm using "Distribute points on Faces" and "Instance on Points" to distribute objects on a plane, and I would like to move/rotate only one of those instances. I want to avoid realizing those instances if possible. How could this be done?

just compare the index of the instance with the index node + compare node, use that for the selection input of set position node. Use position offset input to move your instance.

Awesome, that worked. Thanks a lot! (small addition for clarity: make sure the compare node is set to "integer" and "equal")

glad if it's helpful
